# $_GET without foo

Tags: php, url, get

How can I use download.php?get=file.exe with without the get variable, like download.php?=file.exe, using the $_GET in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `$_SERVER['request_uri']` which would allow you to omit the ? completely, leaving you with URLs like example.com/download.php/file.exe

Then, with a bit of URL rewriting (or implementing a bootstrap controller) you could clean it up even more, resulting in example.com/download/file.exe

Answer (score 9):

You can use $_GET[0] or $_REQUEST[0]

Answer (score 1):

What you need i address rewritting [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) should give you enough information to stat with. Specifically, if you use apache, read about mod_rewrite.

Comment: Seems like I've misunderstood question a bit. Well... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to get everything after the ?.

Edit: Then you could use download.php?file.exe